# VBA/C# workaround for adding bookmarks and index marks in MS Word Online?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have MS Word installed in Windows 10 but typically edit my manuscripts with Word Online typically in Chrome. Works great, but now I need to create an index, so need to add index marks and bookmarks (I'm using the latter is to specify a range for the index mark).

Unless I'm missing something, Word Online doesn't support creating these marks, so I'm thinking I can insert special text identifying the marks when editing in Chrome and next time I'm on Windows 10, use a VBA macro to search for this special text and replace it with the marks.

I'm thinking both marks would use double braces to identify text to be converted. Below is sample text showing inserts that would trigger a single mark, a mark with a range, and a bookmark:

```
Lorem ipsum ultricies sodales magna{{XE magna}} class sit aliquam nisl, 
aptent curabitur{{XE curabitur /r end_xe1}} urna mollis aliquam urna 
aenean sollicitudin, donec elementum class porta tortor ultricies nullam 
aliquet donec tincidunt pretium ipsum magna blandit quam.{{BM end_xe1}}
```

So, the macro would search for text to define bookmarks in the form `{{XE "foo" \r "bar"}}` and `{{BEGIN "bar"}}` and `{{END "bar"}}` and replace associated text with the index marks (some with ranges) and bookmarks.

Before I dive in, my questions are (1) is this the best way to insert index marks and bookmarks into a Word doc while editing with Chrome or does a better design or maybe existing solution? (2) If not, can someone point to some VBA/C# code that accomplishes some or all of the above?

Comment: You are aware that your question violates the guidelines for asking on Stack Overflow - in more ways than one. It's too broad / shows no effort; it's off-topic because you ask for samples; it contains more than one questions and it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: But, yes, what you describe should work, more or less. It would also be possible to code an Office JS add-in that could do all this in Word-Online, but it would be non-trivial (i.e. for professionals).

Comment: Perhaps when you get to the point of wanting to create bookmarks & index entries, you should revert to using the desktop version of Word. It's not apparent what the bookmarks are for, though, as they're usually required for cross-referencing and your post makes no mention of that. Word can also create index entries from a concordance file, obviating the need to add all the entries manually.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts @macropod. The manuscript is 300 pages which would take me a week to do a decent job on the index which is why I'm considering the macros as I have limited access to the desktop version. The bookmarks are used by the index marks to set a range of pages. I did experiment with the concordance file but found that they're of limited use for a decent index.

Comment: @CindyMeister, how was my post too broad? I posted a specific, clear problem with a  specific clear solution and solicited advice as whether there was a better solution before proceeding to code. Regarding effort, I put effort into designing my interface and am soliciting advice so I don't waste time coding a design if a better one exists. Regardless, I plan to post my solution when I'm done for others to use. Your second comment was as unhelpful as your first. I'm sorry if you had a bad day but you shouldn't take it out on people seeking advice.

Answer (score 0):

Coded two functions in C# do what I needed. Been using them for a couple days and find I prefer using these functions over the default GUI approach of Word. (Its more like using LaTeX, though I understand that's not for everyone.) Also frees me from a native install of Word and allows me to index my manuscript using Word online, so using a Chromebook or phone.

For anyone interested, code is below. It recognizes the keys in the form `{{XE "foo" \r "bar"}}` `{{BEGIN "bar"}}` and `{{END "bar"}}` where `BEGIN` and `END` denote the beginning and end of a bookmark. (The bookmark in the index mark is optional). It does some simple error checking and is a bit finicky with spacing (doesn't want any between `{{` and keyword, nor before the `}}`

Function to convert Word bookmarks and index marks to text keys:

```
private void MarksToText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isWordRunning = true;
    try
    {
        object o = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Word is not running");
        isWordRunning = false;
    }

    if (isWordRunning)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application =
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

        if (application == null || application.Documents.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Word is running but no open document found");
        }
        else
        {
            Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
            MessageBox.Show("Converting " + document.Name);

            // convert bookmarks
            int bmCount = 0;
            int xeCount = 0;
            foreach (Bookmark bm in document.Bookmarks)
            {
                bm.Range.InsertBefore("{{BEGIN \"" + bm.Name + "\"}}");
                bm.Range.InsertAfter("{{END \"" + bm.Name + "\"}}");
                bm.Delete();
                bmCount++;
            }

            // convert index marks
            foreach (Field f in document.Fields)
            {
                if (f.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldIndexEntry)
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngField = f.Code;
                    rngField.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
                    rngField.MoveStart(WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
                    string s = @"{{";
                    s += f.Code.Text.ToString().Trim();
                    s += @"}}";
                    rngField.InsertAfter(s);
                    f.Delete();
                    xeCount++;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(@"Converted (" + bmCount + ") bookmarks, (" + xeCount + ") index marks");
        }
    }
}
```

Function to convert text keys to Word bookmarks and index marks:

```
private void TextToMarks(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isWordRunning = true;
    try
    {
        object o = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Word is not running");
        isWordRunning = false;
    }

    if (isWordRunning)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application =
            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

        if (application == null || application.Documents.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Word is running but no open document found");
        }
        else
        {
            Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
            MessageBox.Show("Converting " + document.Name);

            Selection sel = application.Selection;
            sel.Find.ClearFormatting();
            sel.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
            // sel.Find.Wrap = wdFindContinue; // VBA
            sel.Find.Forward = true;

            // convert two text blocks {{BEGIN "foo"}} and {{END "foo"}} into Word bookmarks
            int bmCount = 0;
            int xeCount = 0;
            List<string> bookmarks = new List<string>();
            List<string> bookmarksReferenced = new List<string>();
            bool isOK;  // while-loop flag
            do
            {
                isOK = false;

                sel.SetRange(document.Content.Start, document.Content.End);
                sel.Find.Text = @"\{\{?@\}\}";
                sel.Find.Execute();

                if (sel.Find.Found)
                {
                    //delete the brackets and trim leading and trailing whitespace
                    string cmd = sel.Text.Replace(@"{{", string.Empty);
                    cmd = cmd.Replace(@"}}", string.Empty);
                    cmd.Trim();

                    string[] tokens = cmd.Split(' ');

                    if (tokens[0] == "BEGIN")
                    {

                        string bmName = Regex.Replace(tokens[1], "[\u0022\u0027\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D\u201E]", string.Empty);
                        bookmarks.Add(bmName);

                        sel.SetRange(document.Content.Start, document.Content.End);
                        // using '?' instead of '"' b/c of the different types of quotes
                        sel.Find.Text = @"\{\{BEGIN ?" + bmName + @"?\}\}?@\{\{END ?" + bmName + @"?\}\}";
                        sel.Find.Execute();
                        if (sel.Find.Found)
                        {
                            sel.Bookmarks.Add(bmName);

                            sel.SetRange(document.Content.Start, document.Content.End);

                            // remove tag text
                            sel.Find.Text = @"\{\{BEGIN ?" + bmName + @"?\}\}";
                            sel.Find.Execute();
                            if (sel.Find.Found)
                                sel.Range.Text = "";
                            sel.Find.Text = @"\{\{END ?" + bmName + @"?\}\}";
                            sel.Find.Execute();
                            if (sel.Find.Found)
                                sel.Range.Text = "";
                            bmCount++;
                            isOK = true;
                        }
                        if (!isOK)
                            MessageBox.Show(@"Error processing {{" + cmd + @"}}. Maybe no matching {{END?");
                    }
                    else if (tokens[0] == "XE")
                    {
                        cmd = cmd.Substring(cmd.IndexOf(" ") + 1);
                        cmd.Trim();

                        // remove quotes
                        cmd = Regex.Replace(cmd, "[\u0022\u0027\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D\u201E]", "");

                        // if refs a bookmark
                        string bookmarkParam = @" \r ";
                        if (cmd.Contains(bookmarkParam))
                        {
                            string[] entryAndBookmark = cmd.Split(new[] { bookmarkParam }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            entryAndBookmark[0].Trim();
                            entryAndBookmark[1].Trim();
                            document.Indexes.MarkEntry(sel.Range, Entry: entryAndBookmark[0], BookmarkName: entryAndBookmark[1]);
                            bookmarksReferenced.Add(entryAndBookmark[1]);
                        }
                        else // does not ref a bookmark
                        {
                            document.Indexes.MarkEntry(sel.Range, Entry: cmd);
                        }
                        sel.Range.Text = "";
                        xeCount++;
                        isOK = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (isOK);

            // see if any double curly braces were not processed
            sel.SetRange(document.Content.Start, document.Content.End);
            sel.Find.Text = @"\{\{";
            sel.Find.Execute();
            if (sel.Find.Found)
                MessageBox.Show(@"Error: double braces '{{' skipped. Maybe followed by space? Spaces are not allowed " +
                    @"between braces and commend (E.g., must be '{{BEGIN ""blah""}}'. Or maybe missing closing double braces?");

            // check for missing bookmarks
            foreach (var bm in bookmarksReferenced)
                if (bookmarks.Contains(bm) == false)
                    MessageBox.Show(@"Mark missing bookmark """ + bm + @"""");

            // check for missing marks
            foreach (var bm in bookmarks)
                if (bookmarksReferenced.Contains(bm) == false)
                    MessageBox.Show(@"Bookmark missing index mark""" + bm + @"""");

            // give totals
            MessageBox.Show(@"Converted (" + bmCount + ") bookmarks, (" + xeCount + ") index marks");
        }
    }
}
```